# Set an item flex Combo box

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have one combo box(flex 4),I want to set an item.

```
var tempObject:Object;
tempObject.clientName="Raju";
clientList.selectedItem = tempObject;
```

Is it correct? .But it shows this error

```
*TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.*
```

My combo box:

```
<s:ComboBox id="clientList" width="14%" height="85%"change="clientList_changeHandler(event)"
    dataProvider="{clientListForcombo}" labelField="clientName"
    prompt="Select the  one"/>
```

Comment: you need to add a dataprovider to the combobox, here is a nice example http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS70f0d54f063b9b081aac8d1d1247252e4a0-8000.html

Comment: @PieterWillaert :I already added a dataprovider and also i already have an item as "Raju",I can not set this item on the combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not init tempObject?

try this:

```
var tempObject:Object = new Object();
tempObject.clientName="Raju";
clientList.selectedItem = tempObject;
```